# Button in side a Form

Tags: php

```
<form action='login.php' method='post'>
     <center>   Username : <input type='text' name='username'> Password : <input type='password' name='pass'> <input type='submit' value='Login'></center>
</form>
<a href="reg.php"STYLE="text-decoration: none"><input type='submit' value='Registration'></a>
```

I wondering if it is possible to have my Registration button next to the login without having anything to do with the login.php. If I move it inside of the form then it's going to the login.php and not the reg.php.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have an input inside an anchor.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use submit button in anchor(`<a></a>`) tag

Just provide a text in it

```
<a href="reg.php" STYLE="text-decoration: none">Registration</a>
```

If you want a button in it

Try to use type button not submit (Untested from me)

```
<a href="reg.php" STYLE="text-decoration: none"><input type='button' value='Registration'></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can - you may consider changing the form action to some "formHandler.php", giving both of the submits the same name, and testing the inputs value (each one has to be different) in the formHanlder.php

```
$real_action=$_REQUEST['submit_input_name'];
switch ($real_action){
    case 'register':.....
    case 'login':.......
}
```